# ref not working in controller for extjs4 mvc application

Tags: model-view-controller, view, controller, extjs4, ref

I am trying to build MVC app.

Following is my code of app/controller/project.js file

```js
Ext.define('rt.controller.project', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

stores: ['project'],
models: ['project'] ,   
views: ['project.main', 'project.projectlist'],

refs: [
       {ref: 'projectList', selector: 'projectlist'},
       {ref: 'projectData', selector: 'projectlist dataview'}
       ],


init: function() {
    this.control({
        'projectlist dataview': {
            selectionchange: this.loadProject
        },
        'projectlist button[action=add]': {
            click: this.addProject
        },
        'projectlist button[action=remove]': {
            click: this.removeProject
        }
    });
},

onLaunch: function() {
    console.log(this.getProjectData());
    var dataview = this.getProjectData(),
        store = this.getProjectStore();
     console.log("Stoer = " + store);   
    dataview.bindStore(store);
    dataview.getSelectionModel().select(store.getAt(0));

},


loadProject: function(selModel, selected) {

    console.log("Load Project");

},


addProject: function() {
    console.log("Add Project");
},

removeProject: function() {
    console.log("Remove Project");
},


});
```

Following is code for my app/view/project/projectlist.js

```js
Ext.define('rt.view.project.projectlist', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
alias: 'widget.projectlist',

requires: ['Ext.toolbar.Toolbar'],

title: 'Projects',
collapsible: true,
animCollapse: true,
margins: '5 0 5 5',
layout: 'fit',

initComponent: function() {
    Ext.apply(this, {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'dataview',
            trackOver: true,
            store: this.store,
            cls: 'project-list',
            itemSelector: '.project-list-item',
            overItemCls: 'project-list-item-hover',
            tpl: '<tpl for="."><div class="project-list-item">{name}</div></tpl>',
            listeners: {
                selectionchange: this.onSelectionChange,
                scope: this
            }
        }],

        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [{
                text: 'Add project',
                action: 'add'
            }, {
                text: 'Remove project',
                disabled: true,
                action: 'remove'
            }]
        }]
    });

    this.callParent(arguments);
},

onSelectionChange: function(selmodel, selection) {
    var selected = selection[0],
        button = this.down('button[action=remove]');
    if (selected) {
        button.enable();
    }
    else {
        button.disable();
    }
}
});
```

When I am running my app it shows following error

**dataview is undefined**

in file controller/project.js on line 34 which is following

```js
dataview.bindStore(store);
```

it seems that following is not working in the controller code

```js
refs: [
    {ref: 'projectList', selector: 'projectlist'},
    {ref: 'projectData', selector: 'projectlist dataview'}
],
```

Does any one have any idea about what could cause this?

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem referencing dataview. Here is how I modified my selector string:

```
{ref: 'projectData', selector: 'projectlist > dataview' }
```

That should fix it. But I would like to ask you what `console.log(this.getProjectData());` in onLaunch method displays on console? Also, I don't see a `ref` for projectStore so that you can execute the command:

```
store = this.getProjectStore();
```

Did you miss the `projectStore` reference in the `refs` list?

Comment: Hello Abdel, Thanks for reply. It seems that I solved it. The problem was that 'projectlist' view was not on viewport when application initializes. I am enabling it on click of icon of my desktop.
So I put event in my controller 'projectlist':{render: this.onRenderList} and in onRenderList function, I put code of onLaunch function. So it seems fine now

Comment: Regarding projectStore, should not it be created automatically? I have project store file in my app/store/project.js. I am doing it from example of feed viewer application given in their example folder. In that they have not taken anything like that in ref and it seems to work fine. Let me know if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: mm.. yes.. I overlooked that :) you are correct.. there is no need for ref for store